# How the absolute positioning works here?

Tags: html, css

If the absolute positioning removes the object from regular content flow, then why the `div#container` is still following those boxes (when the boxes' widths are reduced or increased, the `div#container` is too adjusting itself according to that and covering all the boxes. For example, when I set one of the box's positioning to absolute then the `container` too reduces itself)? And also why the `container` is just following the boxes, instead of the whole width (since div is a block level element)?

[image: Screenshot]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div#container {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  position: absolute;
}
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
}
#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}
#p3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}
#p4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
}
```

```html
  <h1>Positioning Elements</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <p id="p1"></p>
    <p id="p2"></p>
    <p id="p3"></p>
    <p id="p4"></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> And also why the container is just following the boxes, instead of the whole width (since div is a block level element)?

That's because you set its positioning to `absolute`, thus forcing it to only take up space that is required by its children.

```
div#container { position: absolute; }
```

If you want to make it take up all the width, remove `absolute` positioning.

---

> If the absolute positioning removes the object from regular content flow, then why the div#container is still following those boxes (when the boxes' widths are reduced or increased, the div#container is too adjusting itself according to that and covering all the boxes.

Add `absolute` positioning to your boxes and the parent `container` will no longer "follow" them.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
div#container {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  position: relative;             // < === HERE ===
}
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#p1 {
  background-color: #A52A2A;
}
#p2 {
  background-color: #DEB887;
}
#p3 {
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
}
#p4 {
  background-color: #FF7F50;
  position: absolute;             // < === HERE ===
}
```

```html
  <h1>Positioning Elements</h1>

  <div id="container">
    <p id="p1"></p>
    <p id="p2"></p>
    <p id="p3"></p>
    <p id="p4"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Concerning OPs last question, what you say makes sense. I just can't seem to find it in the spec. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) actually seems to actually go along with the OPs assumption that the `div` should stay block and thus take up the entire width. I'm probably making an error of assumption somewhere. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When an element has position absolute it means that it position is relative to it's first positioned parent, meaning it's first parent with position relative / absolute / fixed / sticky.

It still behaves the same according to it's children elements.